# Issue: Plot alpha values scaling with Y-Axis/number of observations in ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I haven't found anyone else with this issue. Here is my plot:
[facet plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8C4u.png)

Why are there different alpha values for each facet?

As you can see, the alpha value of the geom_rect() elements seems to scale with the y-axis or number of observations, maybe because I have set these to "free_y" in the facet_wrap() argument. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
plot_data %>%
ggplot(aes(Date, n)) +
geom_rect(data= plot_data, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            aes(xmin=current_date - lubridate::weeks(1), xmax=current_date, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), 
            fill='pink', alpha=0.2) +
geom_col() + 
facet_wrap(~Type, scales = "free_y") +
xlab("Date") +
ylab("Count") +
theme_bw() +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = integer_breaks()) +
scale_alpha_manual(values = 0.2) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you would you mind sharing a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is most likely related to some kind of overplotting. Based on the way you add your rectangles I would guess that you add a rect for each row of your data instead of just one rect per panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR - It seems this is probably due to overplotting.  You have 5 rect geoms drawn in the facet, but probably more than 5 observations in your dataset.  The fix is to summarize your data and associate `geom_rect()` to plot with the summarized dataset.*

Since OP did not provide an example dataset, we can only guess at the reason, but likely what's happening here is due to overplotting.  `geom_rect()` behaves like all other geoms, which is to say that `ggplot2` will draw or add to any geom layer with every observation (row) in the original dataset.  If the geoms are drawn across facets and *overlap in position*, then you'll get overplotting.  You can notice that this is happening based on:

- Different alpha appearing on each facet, even though it should be constant based on the code, and
- The fact that in order to get the rectangles to look like "light red", OP had to use `pink` color and an alpha value of 0.2... which shouldn't look like that if there was only one rect drawn.

#### Representative Example of the Issue

Here's an example that showcases the problem and how you can fix it using `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- mtcars
p <- ggplot(df, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme_bw()
p + geom_rect(
  aes(xmin=200, xmax=300, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
  alpha=0.01, fill='red')
```

[image]

Like OP's case, we expect all rectangles to be the same alpha value, but they are not.  Also, note the alpha value is ridiculously low (`0.01`) for the color you see there.  What's going on should be more obvious if we check number of observations in `mtcars` that falls within each facet:

```
> library(dplyr)
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% tally()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

There's a lower number of observations where `cyl==6` and `cyl==4` has lower observations than `cyl==8`.  This corresponds precisely to the alpha values we see for the geoms in the plot, so this is what's going on.  For each observation, a rectangle is drawn over the same position and so there are 7 rectangles drawn in the middle facet, 14 on the right facet, and 11 on the left facet.

#### Fixing the Issue: Summarize the Data

To fix the issue, you should summarize your data and use the *summarized* dataset for plotting the rectangles.

```
summary_df <- df %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(mean_d = mean(disp))

p + geom_rect(
  data = summary_df,
  aes(x=1, y=1, xmin=mean_d-50, xmax=mean_d+50, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
  alpha=0.2, fill='red')
```

[image]

Since `summary_df` has only 3 observations (one for each group of `cyl`), the rectangles are drawn correctly and now `alpha=0.2` with `fill="red"` gives the expected result.  One thing to note here is that we still have to define `x` and `y` in the `aes()`.  I set them both to `1` because although `geom_rect()` doesn't use them, `ggplot2` still expects to find them in the dataset `summary_df` because we stated that they are assigned to that plot globally up in `ggplot(df, aes(x=..., y=...))`.  The fix is to either move the `aes()` declaration into `geom_point()` or just assign both to be constant values in `geom_rect()`.